# Where is the framework folder in android used for external Jar file?

Tags: android, frameworks

I want to add Cordova to my existing android app. Please tell Where is the framework folder in android used for external Jar file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using android studio you can add this to your gradle dependencies:

`compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])`

then it would be $ProjectDir/libs/your.jar